# How does UIGestureRecognizer work?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

How does `UIGestureRecognizer` work internally? Is it possible to emulate it in iOS < 3.2?

Comment: I left an answer below, but incidentally, I would suggest that you strongly consider whether it's worth building anything of real complexity to support pre-3.2 iOS, which almost nobody uses at this point.

Comment: No, I don't really want to make the whole thing from scratch, I was just wondering if it could be done or not, and if yes, how -- I'm just interested in how it works. Thanks for the link to that video, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a detailed explanation on how they work, it is worth watching [`this video`](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=121) from last year's WWDC.

Answer (score 1):

See the video Deepak mentions for details, but yes, it is something you can build yourself if you want to.

Be sure to ask yourself a couple questions first, though: do you want to recreate the entire recognizer "framework", or just be able to recognize, say, a swipe? If the latter, there should be tons of examples on the web from pre 3.2 days of detecting swipes using the normal touch event handlers.

If you really want to recreate the framework, you can, and it's actually kind of an interesting exercise. The UIKit object does have some hooks into the event pipeline at earlier stages, but you can get a similar result by tracking the touches and building a pipeline of recognizer objects. If you [read the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on UIGestureRecognizer, you'll see that the state management that they use is pretty clearly laid out. You could copy that, and then just build you own custom MyPanGestureRecognizer, MySwipeGestureRecognizer, etc, that derive from a MyGestureRecognizer base. You should have some UIView subclass (MyGestureView) that handles all the touches and runs through its list of MyGestureRecognizers, using the state machine that's implied in the docs.

Comment: I really wonder how would you write logic for swipe btw=) I think it's the trickiest of "standard" gestures since it has to fail quick but same time it should have a good chance to be recognized.